# Запись в одну переменную из разных потоков с подвохом

Tags: java, многопоточность

У меня есть статический HashMap с которым будут работать несколько потоков.
В какой-то момент работы потока, они могут обнаружить, что пара *ключ n - значение n* еще не создано.
Тогда может произойти, что оба потока одновременно упадут в следующий иф:

```
if (map.get("keyN") == null) {
     map.put("keyN", "valueN");
}
```

И попытаются одновременно положить каждый свое значение, или сначала положит значение первый поток, а затем второй. В итоге сохранится значение второго, но первый поток будет думать что сохранилось его значение. А я хочу сделать так, что-бы как только новая пара ключ/значение добавлена, больше никто ее изменить не может.

Вопрос - может ли это сделать следующий код и/или есть способ получше?

```
if (map.get("keyN") == null) {
   synchronized(map) {
      if (map.get("keyN") == null) {
         map.put("keyN", "valueN");
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Да, этот код поможет. Его недостаток - блокировка всего ресурса. В качестве альтернативы можете посмотреть в сторону реализации `ConcurrentHashMap` и её метода `putIfAbsent`

Comment: Благодарю, это именно то что нужно